# Having a hard time getting Google Maps to show in Ionic - "google is not defined"

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have been building an app with Ionic, and I'm having a hard time getting the Google Map to show when I navigate to the map view. It seems as though Cordova is running properly, as it asks me for my location. I have added the whitelist plugin. I have also spent 6 hours trying to get Ionic to display a simple map. I'd just like it to show. Here's my code:

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com/ https://mts0.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
      <script src="cordova.js"></script>


    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
      <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="css/style.css"></script>
      <script src="scss/ionic.app.scss"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive

      .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:



  .state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'tab-home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

   .state('tab.exteriorpainting', {
      url: "/exteriorpainting",
      views: {
        'tab-home': {
          templateUrl: "services/exteriorPainting.html"
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.map', {
      url: "/map",
      views: {
        'tab-home': {
            controller: 'MapCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'templates/map.html'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'tab-login': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-login.html',
          controller: 'DashCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    views: {
      'tab-signup': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-signup.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('tab/home');

});
```

style.css

```
#scroll {
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation) {
 var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  }, function(error){
    console.log("Could not get location");
  });
});
```

map.html

```
<ion-view title="Map">
    <ion-content>
        <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="false"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I'd *love* some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't included the Google Maps API JS library. Hence why 'google' is undefined...

Include the library in your index.html before your app.js by adding:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Find more instructions on how to get started here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Also, the angular google maps library (http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) works really well and I would recommend using it. It has a quick start guide available here: http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use

Comment: Opps! Thanks for that!